# ValueError: External ID not found in the system: todo_report.report_todo_task_template

Tags: python, odoo-12

I tried to add reports to an application but it didn't work and getting the  error:

> ValueError: External ID not found in the system: `todo_report.report_todo_task_template`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
  <report id="action_todo_model_report" 
          string="To-do Report" 
          model="todo.task" 
          report_type="qweb-html" 
          name="todo_report.report_todo_task_template" />

  <template id="report_todo_task_template">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
      <t t-call="web.external_layout">
        <div class="page">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row bg-primary">
                <div class="col-3">name</div>
                <div class="col-2">start date</div>
                <div class="col-2">deadline</div>
                <div class="col-3">Gov</div>
                <div class="col-2"> amount </div>
            </div>
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
              <div class="'row">
                <div class="col-3">
                  <h4><span t-field="o.name" /></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                  <span t-field="o.start_date" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                  <span t-field="o.deadline_date" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                  <span t-field="o.gov_dep_id" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                  <span t-field="o.amount" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </t>
          </div>
        </div>    
      </t>
    </t>
  </template>
</odoo>
```

This is the message which the browser showing it

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

What is my mistake ?
How can you help me?

And I add  the report in  `__manifest__` as a data

Comment: Try defining `report` after `template` definition.

Comment: I did but no effect

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether your 'XML ID' actually exist or not in Odoo, By activating developer mode and then Settings -> sequences & identifiers -> External Identifiers. Search 'report_todo_task_template' in the Search Bar then if you see a record over their just click on it and then copy the whole ID from the detailed view. This helped me because while creating a module i made 'report' plural as 'reports' so you can find the exact ID in the Settings.

Comment: For me it was a namespace issue.

I had <field name="report_template" ref="action_report_saleorder"/>

it should

<field name="report_template" ref="sale.action_report_saleorder"/>

Without the sale. namespace it looked under my_addon. namespace -> myaddon.action_report_saleorder...

I know my case belongs to custom email templates, but i think this behaviour occurs in other use cases as well...

Thanks for the hint in searching the ext. identifiers!